# DFT and inverse problem

Tags: optimization, convolution, image-processing, fast-fourier-transform, inverse-problems

Let two functions $I,J:\{0,1,\ldots,n\}\times \{0,1,\ldots,m\} \mapsto \{0,1,\ldots,p\}$ and $h$ a $v\times v$ matrix ($v\ll n,m$) such that
$$
J = I * \underbrace{h*\ldots *h}_{p \text{ times}}
$$
where $*$ is the convolution operator.

Given $J$ and $h$, is it possible to retrieve $I$ ?

---

I tried using the Discrete Fourier Transform (DFT), but I obtain some instability since the DFT of $h$, $\hat h$, may contain 
small terms (especially when we raise it element-wise at the power $p\simeq 25$ ).

To overcome this instability, I was thinking to solve the optimization problem:
$$
\min_{X\in M_{np}(\mathbb{R})} \quad \lVert\hat J- X\hat{\times} (\hat h)^p\lVert^2
$$ 
where $\hat{\times}$ is the element-wise multiplication.

I wonder if I can derive an analytical solution anf more generally if I there would be an other method to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried regularisation?